Better alternative for writing $\circ\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\bullet$
I've want to write $\circ\!\!-\!\!\!-\!\!\bullet$ for notating laplace transformations, but have not found a better way than above command. Is there an existing one or do i need to create my own?

No, the symbol i mean is ◦−−−−−• in "cleartext"

Just use the character ⊶ directly. (U+22B6)

@jose why was this closed as a duplicate of a question about script L?

If you use an unicode engine, it is available through the command \origof provided by the package unicode-math (code U+022B6).
Example :
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

$\origof$

\end{document}



Thank you, that's great. Unfortunately since i'm using MathJax to render my notes i won't be able to use it.

@einzigartigerhummer
Mathjax is off-topic often in TeX.SE.

@einzigartigerhummer You should be able to use the same character ⊶ directly in mathjax just as you can without mathjax, on this web page

You should, to begin with, define a command for the job.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% Laplace direct transform
\newcommand{\ldt}{\mathrel{\circ}\mathrel{\!}\mathrel{-}\mathrel{\!}\mathrel{\bullet}}

\begin{document}

$f\ldt g$

\end{document}


If you switch to unicode-math, just modify the command:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

%\newcommand{\ldt}{\mathrel{\circ}\mathrel{\!}\mathrel{-}\mathrel{\!}\mathrel{\bullet}}
\newcommand{\ldt}{\origof}

\begin{document}

$f\ldt g$

\end{document}


For MathJax, use \unicode.

